Why am I receiving an ECONNREFUSED error when trying to connect a Directus instance to Postgresql?
I'm trying to setup an instance of Directus for a personal project of mine, with Postgresql as the database. However, I'm getting the following error when running docker compose up:
directus-1  | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5432
directus-1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16) {
directus-1  |   errno: -111,
directus-1  |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
directus-1  |   syscall: 'connect',
directus-1  |   address: '::1',
directus-1  |   port: 5432
directus-1  | }

I have another (Django) application which is able to connect to this database, but it's not using Docker or any other kind of container or VM. Postgresql is running on the same physical machine as the Docker container, but it's running outside of the container.
Here is my docker config file:
version: "3"
services:
  directus:
    image: directus/directus:10.10.5
    ports:
      - 8055:8055
    volumes:
      - ./uploads:/directus/uploads
      - ./extensions:/directus/extensions
    environment:
      KEY: <somekey>
      SECRET: <somesecret>
      ADMIN_EMAIL: <someemail>
      ADMIN_PASSWORD: <somepassword>
      DB_CLIENT: "pg"
      DB_HOST: "localhost"
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_DATABASE: "directuspcm"
      DB_USER: <dbuser>
      DB_PASSWORD: <dbpassword>
      WEBSOCKETS_ENABLED: "true"

My best guess is that the issue is because postgresql isn't being managed by Docker, but I'm still fairly new to Docker (and containers), so I'm neither sure if that's the case or how I'd fix it.
Why am I getting a ECONNREFUSED error when trying to connect a Directus instance to Postgresql?

If the database isn't running in a container, where is it running?  Outside a container on the same physical host machine?

@DavidMaze Yes, it's running on the same physical machine, but outside the container.

localhost usually refers to the current container in Docker.  If you're using Docker Desktop, try setting DB_HOST: host.docker.internal.  The linked question has more details and options for other configurations.

@DavidMaze That allows me to connect. Thanks! I'll take a look at the linked question as well.
